# mime extracted emails back to mbox format

Tags: perl, mime, mime-message, mbox

I have a special mbox file where each message in the mbox is has one or more attached messages.  These were created from being forwarded as an attachment.  I have a perl script that uses [MIME::Tools](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Tools) and [MIME::Parser](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Parser) to parse that mbox file. It can pipe these files to another program (spamassassin), or save them as individual text files which is what I'm doing.  I believe these individual files are RFC822 format (not positive).  Each text file does not start with "From: ..." so I can't simply cat them back together.

I need a way to reassemble these extracted files back into mbox (mbxcl2) format.  Is there a tool or script I can use to reassemble these extracted files?

I tried having my script output them into a single file as they parsed, with a `From me\@myserver.com  Fri Sep  1 15:18:53 2017\n`.  This is enough for mailx viewing on the server, but Dovecot complains: `dovecot: imap(me): Error: Syncing INBOX failed: Mailbox isn't a valid mbox file`

So I apparently need to do more than just add the "From " separator.

Comment: A quick search reveals https://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailboxFormat/mbox - it mentions separating messages via  Content-Length headers ( see "Escapting From" ). Have you investigated that?

Comment: Yeah, that's part of mbxcl2 mentioned in the original Q.  Looking for a already available tool to put these back together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally I was writing \n\nFrom me...\n"  To ensure the required blank line in front of each From...  I think the initial blank line is what Dovecot was unhappy with.

I rewrote it so as the original parsing script was breaking the message attachments out, I added the 2 lines below (before and after the line that was writing the individual messages).  So now it did not start off with a blank line.

```
print OUT "From me\@myserver.com  Fri Sep  1 15:18:53 2017\n";
$ent->bodyhandle->print(\*OUT);
print OUT "\n\n";
```

OUT is the resulting mbx file.  Since the original messages had the content-length header, at least Dovecot and Outlook are happy with the resulting format.  So I'm good now I think.